# react grid layout - resize by fixed amount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

This [link](https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/17-resizable-handles.html) is the default demo. right now, when resizing, it will increment/ decrement by 1 px, is there a way to increment by fixed amount? for example when dragging the handle, it will increment / decrement by 50px

This is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-bush-3lvt7?file=/src/ShowcaseLayout.js) provided.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The handle is supposed to follow the mouse cursor. Once you let it go, it adjusts itself to the nearest breakpoint (e.g. every 50px). That seems to just be the way react-grid-layout is designed.

Comment: but it would be a nice feature to have

Comment: I personally don't see what the use-case is, but if you feel strongly about it I suggest you contact the creator of react-grid-layout and discuss the matter.